# RegEx to find whole word, but not abbreviation

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using RegEx in my .htaccess file to determine what URIs get sent to my router file. I have a problem though because one page that I need to route contains a string that I'm filtering out, causing that URI not to be sent to the router. I don't want the URIs with "adm" in them to be sent to the router, but this also means that it filters out URIs with strings like "admonish" or "administrate".

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !(^adm|^ajax|^google([a-z0-9])|^tools|^swf|^confirm|^style) index.php [nc]
```

I've tried things like `RewriteRule !(^adm(![in])|^ajax|^google([a-z0-9])|^tools|^swf|^confirm|^style) index.php [nc]` and `RewriteRule !(^adm(!in)|^ajax|^google([a-z0-9])|^tools|^swf|^confirm|^style) index.php [nc]`, but with no success.

What is the correct way to match a portion of a word if it is not followed by characters other than "/"?

EDIT - This is the current Rewrite as suggested:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !(^(?i)\badm(?=[a-z])|^ajax|^google([a-z0-9])|^tools|^swf|^confirm|^style) index.php [nc]
```

Still no luck with this, though.

**UPDATE** - Full .htaccess file:

```
   DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(adm|ajax|google([a-z0-9])|tools|swf|confirm|style) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# Rewrite requests for sitemap.xml
RewriteRule sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php?target=google [L]
# Rewrite requests for urllist.txt
RewriteRule urllist.txt$ sitemap.php?target=yahoo [L]

Options -MultiViews


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Custom 404 page
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# You can add custom pages to handle 500 or 403 pretty easily, if you like.
# If you are hosting your site in subdirectory, adjust this accordingly
#    e.g. ErrorDocument 404 /subdir/404.html
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?e=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?e=500


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# UTF-8 encoding
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# A little more security
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# To avoid displaying the exact version number of Apache being used, add the
# following to httpd.conf (it will not work in .htaccess):
# ServerTokens Prod

# "-Indexes" will have Apache block users from browsing folders without a
# default document Usually you should leave this activated, because you
# shouldn't allow everybody to surf through every folder on your server (which
# includes rather private places like CMS system folders).
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

# Block access to "hidden" directories or files whose names begin with a
# period. This includes directories used by version control systems such as
# Subversion or Git.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

# Block access to backup and source files. These files may be left by some
# text/html editors and pose a great security danger, when anyone can access
# them.
<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

# Increase cookie security
<IfModule php5_module>
  php_value session.cookie_httponly true
  php_value error_log /logs/php_errors.log
</IfModule>


# prevent access to PHP error log
<Files php_errors.log>
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy All
</Files>
```

EDIT AGAIN:
I have also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !((adm[^/]+)/|ajax|google([a-z0-9])|tools|swf|confirm|style) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/((.*)/adm/(.*)|ajax|google([a-z0-9])|tools|swf|confirm|style) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Negative Lookahead**

If I'm understanding correctly, the basic pattern you're looking for (with possible refinements) is:

```
adm(?![a-z])
```

- `(?![a-z])` is a lookahead that ensures that the following character is not a letter.
- In `mod-rewrite`, you can make this case-insensitive with `(?i)adm(?![a-z])`

Comment: Is it only `adm` + (space or `/` or end of string)? If so, that's what I have at the bottom, if not, let me know so I can tweak. :)

Comment: The only thing that should be allowed to follow the string would be another letter. If it's a `/`, it should not go to the router. For example: `example.com/adm` or `example.com/adm/` should not go to the router, while `example.com/history/admin` or `example.com/history/admin/` would.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I revised the regex. Let me know if we need to tweak it for your context of use.

Comment: Hey, I gave you the regex for `adm` followed by letters... Sounds like you want to exclude the opposite (double negation), that is simply `adm(?![a-z])` :)

Comment: Still no love. I'm going to see if I can make it work with another `RewriteCond`. I've spent too long on this as it is. lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add one more negative `RewriteCond` here to skip `/adm/` URI from this rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(adm|ajax|google([a-z0-9])|tools|swf|confirm|style) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !adm index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Same issue as with the other answers. I just get a blank page, but 200 OK status.

Comment: Open Firebug and then visit your page again. Tell me which URLs are giving 404 to you? I suspect your css/image/js files are giving you 404. For that make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: There's never a 404. It returns a regular 200. Just with a blank page. All URLs containing "adm" are still filtered.

Comment: Still no love. Looks like I may have to just restrict some usernames.

Comment: I suspect other rule in your .htaccess conflicting. Can you upload your complete .htaccess in question. Also make sure there is no other .htaccess in any of the sub directories.

Comment: Updated the question to include the full .htaccess code. And there is only one subdirectory under this domain's root which holds another .htaccess file, and that is the cache directory to ensure no one can access the files contained therein.

Comment: You .htaccess is not showing my suggested rule in it.

Comment: Updated to show your suggestion in the full .htaccess. I'm still not sure why it's not relaying to my router.

Comment: Ok What URL are you entering in the browser that shows your blank page?

Comment: An example URL would be like: `http://beansworthy.fluidvector.com/history/admin/` or `http://beansworthy.fluidvector.com/admiral/`

Comment: ok if you comment out this particular rule in my answer then `http://beansworthy.fluidvector.com/history/admin/` loads file?

Comment: I tried a couple of different things: when I comment out all of the lines you suggested, I get a 404 on the URL above. Uncommenting only `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` causes the blank page.

Comment: Still just getting the blank page.

Comment: What is your apache version?

Comment: `apache2ctl -V`:
`Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Feb  1 2014 21:26:04`

Comment: Ok do you have .htaccess in the `/history/` or `/history/admin/` directories?

Comment: They are not actually directories. Just rewrites to a the router, which dispatches to a file like `view.php?mode=history&id=admin`

Comment: ok just add `R` flag like `RewriteRule !adm index.php [L,NC,R]` and then try to visit `http://beansworthy.fluidvector.com/history/admin/` to see how it behaves.

Comment: Adding the `R` flag does make the URL to throw a 404, but it causes _everything_ to redirect to index.php, including URLs that usually route fine such as `http://example.com/user/login/`

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the opposite?

- If it contains "`/adm/`" (including "slash") then stop
- Otherwise redirect all to `index.php`

Like that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)/adm/(.*) - [QSA,L]

RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]
```